# preg_replace pattern doesn't work with HTML tags

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace, multiline

I'm using a `preg_replace` pattern to replace an nth instance (`$occurrence`) of a keyword (`$search`) from a string (`$subject`).

```
$search = preg_quote($search);
return preg_replace("/^((?:(?:.*?$search){".--$occurrence."}.*?))$search/", "$1$replace", $subject);
}
```

The pattern works fine with plain text, but if there was an HTML tag such as `<br />` it would stop.

I don't know much about regular expressions, I got my code from [here](https://vijayasankarn.wordpress.com/2017/01/03/string-replace-nth-occurrence-php/).

I need help fixing the pattern to ignore consider the present of HTML tags.

**EDIT:** Turned out the problem isn't with HTML Tags. The problem is the linebreaks.

If the `$subject` has line breaks it will fail to match the `$search` after the first line break.

Example:

```
$subject = 'This is the first line
This is the second line
This is the third line';
```

Now try to match the second of third line keyword, it won't work.

Comment: Do you mean if the search string has an HTML tag, or if the subject has one?

Comment: The subject is which has an HTML tag.

Comment: give us the passing and failing examples. it might be as easy as wrapping $subject with strip_tags($subject) if you don't want html in the string

Comment: No, I can't strip the HTML Tags. Let's assume the subject is `This is the first line.<br />This is the second line.`. The first `line` search string will pass with `$occurrence` equals 1, while the second one will not pass with `$occurrence` equals 2. This happens because of the HTML tag `<br />`.

Comment: Couldn't resist linking to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, I've made a little [demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/FCCE76990) and it produces the expected results.

Comment: I've edited my question. Please check it.

Comment: @nick - yes you changed the regex delimeter to "|" which is what I was trying to say in my reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for searching in multiline mode you need to add `s` at the end of regex, so it will continue search when there are line breaks.

more read [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

is this working?

```
$search = preg_quote($search);
return preg_replace("/^((?:(?:.*?$search){".--$occurrence."}.*?))$search/s", "$1$replace", $subject);
}
```

Comment: Yes!! It's working! Never thought it will be that simple change. Thanks alot!